Log-transformation and outliers
I am applying a logarithmic transformation to all variables that seem to have outliers (based on the boxplots). My question is, for instance if I have a variable like 'Age', where there are values over 100, perform log-transformation, do I still need to perform trimming?

Log transformations don't treat outliers, they treat skew such as the right-skew from the distribution on the left in the next figure:

For outliers you'd either trim them (i.e. drop the outlier) or cap them to some statistical value (e.g. 3 times the standard deviation from the mean). You can start by taking a look at these outlier handling options.
Image source: https://medium.com/@kyawsawhtoon/log-transformation-purpose-and-interpretation-9444b4b049c9
